# Does the Mind Shield improve a psionic's ability to attack with their Psi attacks?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

Last night I was moving in to the later stages of the game and recently gained access to Psi armour and the Mind Shield.

If I recall, the description for the Mind Shield implies it is a defensive gadget, but I notice that (like the Psi armour) it provides a bonus to the Will of the wearer.

Does this bonus to Will mean it improves the 'attack' strength of a Psionic who happens to be using one? Or are Psionics' attacks uneffected by their Will score?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**As of version 1.0.0.20072 (the so-called `update 3`) `Mind Shield` increases `Will` the same way as `Psi armor` does: both for psi-attacks and for psi-defense.**

This is noted in ["Mind shield" article on wikia](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Mind_Shield).

Yesterday I played this game on `Classic` difficulty. My squad of all psionic warriors has an encounter with `Chryssalid` monsters. I checked chances to `Mind Control` one of them (it was unharmed). Here is what I got

```
                    Soldier 1   Soldier 2
Base Will:          95          100
Psi Armor:          Equipped    Equipped
Mind Shield:        Equipped    Not equipped
Chance to Mind
Control Chryssalid: 85%         60%
```

This clearly shows that Mind Shield is used to calculate chances for both psi-offense and psi-defense.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure, but it seems to me that Mind Shield only provides defence, and does not provide a boost in every aspect like Psi Armor does.

In-game, when you equip Psi Armour on a Psionic, the stat might show 74+20, for example. When you equip Mind Shield, it becomes 74*+30, where * is a small blue whirlwind. I guess this means that offensive power stays 74, and that the game seems to be able to tell a difference between offensive and defensive uses of will.

It also wouldn't make any sense if whole, very expensive armor would add only 20 defence when a much cheaper and easier to use gadget provides 30.

The description of the device says that it only increases resistance. So until proven otherwise: it's only defensive.

Answer (score 1):

Mind Shields boost Psionic attacks including Mind Control.

In my X-COM Enemy Within classic game, I have a gifted Heavy class soldier with Psi armour and Mind Shield. After sustaining some injuries after a UFO crash site mission, the Heavy needed 4 days to heal.  While he was being healed, I restored the Heavy's Psi armour, Mind Shield, Heavy Plasma, Blaster and SCOPE.  To my surprise, the game restored a spare Mind Shield to this Heavy class soldier on returning to duty after being healed to reach a total Will score of 197 = 117 (base Will) + 20 (Psi Armour) + 2x 30 (Mind Shield).

Incidentally, the game does not allow any gifted soldiers to carry a second Mind Shield normally. The above seems to be a game bug; furthermore, I could not add a second Mind Shield back once it was removed - restoring a saved game let me continue playing the game using this Heavy soldier with 197 Will, which guaranteed 100% chance in mind controlling all Ethereal aliens (apart from Uber Ethereal)!